# PHPmailer fails on live

Tags: php, email

Never ran into this problem before in all my years of web development, but oddly enough a site is acting up.

We always use phpmailer to get the job done when sending emails, it is hooked into our backend package that we use to connect all our clients.  All the clients are on the same server and everyone else is working except this site.

Has anyone ever ran into mail not sending live but will send locally and why this happens and how can I fix it.  It's being called no different then the rest of them so I'm scratching head trying to figure this out.  We do not send via SMTP.

Comment: Have you checked if the version of PHP at local match to the servers and PHPMailer supports that?

Comment: Ya everything checks out, like I said everything else works just not this client and it was setup no different then any of the rest.

Comment: I would try tearing it down, and doing it again. Try making a change somewhere, and see if you can affect some sort of result. Determine if its software, or environment related. Something is different, otherwise you wouldn't get the errant behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an internal SSL DNS, even though it is the same server it resolves a different DNS so there was some conflict there.  So really there was no answer to the question since after all it wouldn't work the same way.  Thanks for the comments though.